# Возможен ли промах по кешу в NodeJS и как его получить?

Tags: javascript, массивы, node.js, оптимизация, ecmascript-6

В курсе института "Организация вычислительных систем" нам рассказывали, что *промах по кешу* это когда запрашиваемые данные отсутствуют в кэше процессора и их нужно подгружать из основного источника.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Однако, мне не понятно, о каких данных идет речь и как вызвать подобное синтетически. Исходя из [этого](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16700447/7388307) ответа, оптимизация по кешу производится через корректировку алгоритма, чтобы избежать фрагментации данных при обращении.

```
/* Array.prototype.flat polyfill */
Array.prototype.flat = function() {
    this.reduce((a, v) => Array.isArray(v) ? a.concat(v.flat()) : a.concat(v), []);
};
/* Cache test */
const len = 100;
const generateArr = (len) =>  {
    const mat = [...new Array(len)].map(() => 
        [...new Array(len)].map(() => Math.round(Math.random() * 10))
    );
    return new Uint8Array(mat.flat(Infinity))
};
const arr = generateArr(len)
/* {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, n} */
const testFriendly = () => {
    let total=0;    
    for (let x=0;x!=len;x+=10) {
        for (let y=0;y!=10;y++) {
            total+=arr[x+y];
        }
    }
};
/* {0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 1, 11, 12, n}*/
const testUnfriendly = () => {
    let total=0;
    for (let y=0;y!=10;y++) {
        for (let x=0;x!=len;x+=10) {
            total+=arr[x+y];
        }
    }
};
const test = () => {
    console.time("Cache-friendly");
    for (let i=0; i!=7000; i++) {
        testFriendly();
    }
    console.timeEnd("Cache-friendly");
    console.time("Cache-unfriendly");
    for (let i=0; i!=7000; i++) {
        testUnfriendly();
    }
    console.timeEnd("Cache-unfriendly");
};
test()
test()
test()
test()
```

После того, как отработает JIT, дружелюбный тест выполняется быстрее, но не всегда. Это промах по кешу?

[image: П]

А может ли вообще прикладной программист получить промах по кешу на платформе NodeJS? Существуют ли синтетические примеры или анти-паттерны, чтобы гарантированно получить промах по кешу и не допускать подобного в production коде?